# Removing rows from QTreeWidget (qt programming)

Tags: qt, kde-plasma, qtreewidget

what's the best way to remove a row (QTreeWidgetItem) from a QTreeWidget?

The QTreeWidget content has been set by:

```
myQTreeWidget->insertTopLevelItems(0, items); // items = QList<QTreeWidgetItem*>
```

then I remove an item from my QList "items" and I try to clear/reset the QTreeWidget

```
packList->clear();    
packList->insertTopLevelItems(0, items);
```

but my app crashes here!
Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that calling `packList->clear()` deletes the tree widget items contained by the tree.  (See the documentation about `QTreeWidget::clear()`, which includes a note about the items being removed from the tree before deleting.)  You'll either need to find a way to remove the items, or not maintain a list of them separately from the tree.

On a slightly-related note, if you are trying to keep track of other data along with the tree, I'd recommend you try to use the models paradigm.  In non-trivial cases, it has usually been worth my while to convert to that technique, rather than using the widgets/items.

Answer (score 1):

From what [this documentation](http://docs.huihoo.com/pyqt/pyqt4/html/qtreewidget.html#takeTopLevelItem) says, you should be able to do it with:

```
packList->takeTopLevelItem(index);
```

Which returns removes and returns the item at the supplied index.